# python what is wrong in my regular expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this text:

```
1 Bedroom Apartment To Rent In Aldar Tower, Dubai Marina
```

I want to extract `"Aldar Tower"` and `"Dubai Marina"`

This is what I tried:

```
areaAndBuilding = re.search("\* Rent In \s*", value)
area = areaAndBuilding.split(",")[0]
building = areaAndBuilding.split(",")[1]
```

but the problem is that `areaAndBuilding` is always `None`.

Comment: If you have a regex question, it's helpful to tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different regex that uses `re.match` instead of `re.search`, because you only want to match once (`search` is for multiple matches):

```
areaAndBuilding = re.match(".* Rent In (.*), (.*)", value)
```

Then you can access your desired elements using `re.group`:

```
area = areaAndBuilding.group(1)     # Aldar Tower
building = areaAndBuilding.group(2) # Dubai Marina
```

In your code, `areaAndBuilding` was always `None` because your regex was incorrect, so there was no match. The best way to check if your regexes work is to test them outside of Python; I recommend using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: why `re`? i thing you mean `areAndBuilding` in the group statment ?

Comment: @michaelSalam Oops, yes; I'll change that

Comment: @michaelSalam I've changed my code - does it work for you?

Comment: thank you it work, i need 6 minute to accept the answer, thanks a lot

Comment: @michaelSalam No problem!